# Difference between backpacks with same ability

Tags: the-bureau-xcom-declassified

I noticed that are [many backpacks](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Backpacks_(The_Bureau:_XCOM_Declassified)) with similar abilities but with something extra.

For instance

- Gunner Pack: **Reduces damage from enemy attacks** + increases magazine size for all weapons, allowing agents to fire longer bursts.
- Guardian Pack: **Reduces damage taken from all attacks.**

So, is there some place that describes how much is reduced or in what percentage it's reduced?

In that specific case, I imagine the Guardian Pack reduces much more damage than the gunner pack because that's the only thing it does... but I don't want to walk around with a Guardian pack if the reduction of the gunner pack is exactly the same and Gunner also does something else!

I already searched [here](https://guides.gamepressure.com/thebureauxcomdeclassified/guide.asp?ID=21273) and [here](https://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php/Equipment_(Bureau)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [Xcom Wikia article](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Backpacks_(The_Bureau:_XCOM_Declassified)), Gunner packs reduce damage by 10% while Guardian packs reduce damage by 20%.
Packs with multiple perks offer less effect while packs with only 1 perk give more bonus.

Comment: Do you have the source of that info?